# Is there a default normal-mode command for `:write`?

Tags: key-bindings, save

I know `ZZ` will write and quit, and `ZQ` will quit without saving.  Is there another such command to write the buffer without doing anything else, or should I map one myself?  I'd like to know if there's something I know will work on other people's Vim configurations.

Comment: not in `vim`, not sure about `neovim`.

Comment: I don't understand the "other people's configurations" part. Are you writing a plugin and concerned it will play nicely? If so, stick to the built-in commands. There's no way of knowing who puts what in their `vimrc`s or plugins.

Comment: Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a mapping like `:nnoremap ZW <Cmd>write<CR>`.

Having said that, `:w<CR>` has always seemed reasonably short to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware.

The documentation gather the commands and their corresponding shortcut:

- `ZZ` is close to `:x`
- `ZQ` is close to `:q!`

I suppose any shortcut should be close to `:w` :-)